# datetime object javascript save to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime

I have a really interesting problem that I'm fighting all day long so
my Techstack is ReactJS, NodeJS (Express) and MySQL. I try save `datetime` value in my MySQL and display this value in my ReactJS Application.

My problem:
When I generated `new Data()`, my object looked like this:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
```

`Fri Jan 04 2019 01:23:10 GMT+0100 (czas środkowoeuropejski standardowy)`

```
var json = JSON.stringify(date);
console.log(json);
```

`"2019-01-04T00:23:10.525Z"`

This object has been saved in the database as one hour too small. (`2019-01-04 00:23:10`) but when I displayed this object in my frontend, the hour was displayed correctly. (`2019-01-04 01:23:10`).

I would like to **correctly save the time to the database** and **correctly display it in the application**.

I've already found a solution to save the time to mysql correctly:

```
  const x = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
  const localISOTime = `${new Date(Date.now() - x)
    .toISOString()
    .slice(0, -1)}Z`;
```

...but I don't know, how to correctly display it on the application side.
I try use `moment.js`, but I don't know how to use it correctly.

Comment: MySQL stores dates in UTC and converts them again on output. So if your timezone is not UTC, you will *always* see a difference in the stored value and the displayed value.

Comment: You're doing this backwards. Your database should be holding the UTC time, not the local time. You can then convert to the UTC time back to local time on the client via something akin to [`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: When I write: `SELECT now()` in MySQL, I have corectly result: 
2019-01-04 01:23:10` so MySQL data time zone is set okay.